# Questions regarding second normal form

Tags: normalization

I understand that in order to fulfill 2.NF, attributes must not be dependent on part of the key. Now, the question is, let's say we have a relation R with a set of attributes {A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K} and its functional dependencies {A→GH, B→IJ, C→A, F→B, FC→DK, K→E} and the candidate keys C **AND** F. Do these FDs like C→A violate 2.NF because it is not fully functionally dependent on **BOTH** F **AND** C ?

So the question is

> Do attributes in functional dependencies need to be dependent on the whole set of candidate keys - in this case FC ? Or is the dependency on one of the keys sufficient to fulfill 2.NF ?

Comment: Are `C` and `F` candidate keys by themselves? Or is their compound `(C,F)` a candidate key?

Comment: @ypercube C itself is a candidate key and F itself is a candidate key.

Comment: So, you also have `C->ABDEFGHIJK` and `F->ABCDEGHIJK`. I wonder why you haven't given these before, too. In this case, there is no part of a candidate key, all candidate keys have only one attribute.

Comment: @ypercube I tried to evaluate the NF of my given example here -> http://www.koffeinhaltig.com/fds/normalformen.php?attrs=A+B+C+D+E+F+G+H+I+J+K&fds=A+-%3E+G+H%2C+B+-%3E+I+J%2C+C+-%3E+A%2C+F+-%3E+B%2C+F+C+-%3E+D+K%2C+K+-%3E+E&language=en which tells me that it is not in 2.NF, as attributes need to depend on both candidate keys...

Comment: As in my previous comment, if all your dependencies are the ones you show in the question, then your only candidate key is `CF`. `C` and `F` are not.

Comment: Ok , sorry I think I misinterpreted the information. CF is the candidate key.

Comment: @ypercube But let's say we had CB and FA as candidate keys. If I specified CB as the PK Would  a dependency like {F -> DE}  violate the 2.NF ?

Comment: Yes, it would violate 2NF.

Comment: @ypercube So I have to take all possible candidate keys into account ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If all your dependencies are those you have shown: `{A->GH, B->IJ, C->A, F->B, FC->DK, K->E}` then you have come to the wrong conclusion.

Your only candidate key is `CF`. The `C` and `F` are not candidate keys on their own.

Therefore, the `F->B` dependency (and the `C->A` as well) means that the relation violates 2NF.

---

For the other question, if you had for example these dependencies:

```
BC -> AF
AF -> BC
 F -> DE
```

where the candidate keys are `BC` and `AF`, then again the `F -> DE` would mean that the relation violates 2NF. To be in 2NF would mean that there is no dependency on any part of any candidate key.